# Deploy/convert trained AWS SageMaker MXNet Model to iOS devices

Tags: object-detection, amazon-sagemaker, mxnet, coreml, coremltools

I trained a MXnet SSD resnet-50 model with SageMaker Object Detection Algorithm and want to use it on iOS devices. Therefore I need to convert it to the Apple CoreML format. I tried with [mxnet-to-coreml](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/tools/coreml).

Maybe there are better ways to do it?
Does anyone know a convenient way to achieve this task?

My model consists of two files:

- resnet50_ssd_model-symbol.json
- resnet50_ssd_model-0000.params

Before converting the model, I set it to deploy-state by using "deploy.py" provided by [MXnet](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/example/ssd).

The [mxnet-to-coreml](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/tools/coreml) converter fails with the following error:

> raise TypeError("MXNet layer of type %s is not supported." % layer)
>       TypeError: MXNet layer of type _copy is not supported.

I invoked the converter script like this:

```
python mxnet_coreml_converter.py --model-prefix='ssd_resnet50_512' -- 
epoch=0 --input-shape='{"data":"3, 512, 512"}' --mode=classifier --pre- 
processing-arguments='{"image_input_names":"data"}' --output- 
file="resnet50.mlmodel"
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/13965), this layer ("_copy") (which is MXNet operator) is not yet supported by the convertor from MXNet to CoreML. There is a feature request for this.